# Implement simple PPO Agent in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I read this good [article](https://learningai.io/projects/2017/07/28/ai-gym-workout.html) about the Proximal Policy Optimization algorithm, and now I want update my VanillaPG agent to a PPO agent to learn more about it. However, I'm still not sure how to implement this in real code, especially since I'm using a simple discrete action space.

So what I do with my VPG Agent is, if there are 3 actions, the network outputs 3 values (out), on which I use softmax (p) and use the result as a distribution to choose one of the actions. For training, I take the states, actions and advantages and use this loss function:

```
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(advantages * tf.log(ch_action_p_values))
```

How can I extend this algorithm to use PPO for discrete actions? All of the implementations I found work with continuous actions spaces. I'm not sure if I have to change my loss function to the first one used in the article. And I'm not even sure of which probabilities I have to calculate KLD. Are prob_s_a_* and D_KL single values for the whole batch, or one value for each sample? How can I calculate them in TF for my agent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it also with discrete state without any problem (I never tried, though). The probability `prob_s_a_*` you are talking about are the probabilities of drawing the sampled actions with the current policy (one value per sample). 
PPO does not use `D_KL` (the KL divergence), as from its experiments it performed worse (they just clip the probabilities ratio).

So you need just to add a placeholder for the old log prob and clip the ratio between the new log prob (`tf.log(ch_action_p_values)`) and the old log ones.

Here is an example (`e_clip` is the clipping value, in the paper they use 0.2)

```
    vanilla_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(advantages * tf.log(ch_action_p_values))

    old_log_probs = tf.placeholder(...)
    log_probs = tf.log(ch_action_p_values)
    prob_ratio = tf.exp(log_prob - old_log_probs)
    clip_prob = tf.clip_by_value(prob_ratio, 1.-e_clip, 1.+e_clip)
    ppo_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.minimum(tf.multiply(prob_ratio, advantages), tf.multiply(clip_prob, advantages)))
```

Beside the usual `advantages` and `ch_action_p_values`, you need to feed the loss with `old_log_probs`, computed as the log probability of the current policy on the sampled actions.

Comment: I thought the main concept of PPO was to constrain KL divergence by adding a regularization term to the loss. That's also what's done in the article with loss2. I will try your solution.

Comment: Not really. PPO idea is to clip the surrogate objective function that TRPO (and many other RL algorithms) use. [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf) is the paper. Actually they didn't test `clipping + KL`, but only `no clipping nor KL` vs `only clipping` vs `only KL` (section 6.1). I think I tried by myself `clipping + KL` and it wasn't better than just clipping, but I may be wrong.